# powershell out-file writing zero bytes

Tags: powershell, select-into-outfile, convertto-json

I am trying to export the `SQL Server` query results chunks in to `.json` file. Here I have large table around the 90GB I need to automate the script using the pagination approach.

The following Powershell script is generating within the `For` loop in `c#` application and working fine, but after some time in a random point the `Out-File` is not writing and giving zero bytes file. May be you can help!

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select NAME,FULL_NAME,DOB,GENDER,ADDRESS from [222db] ORDER BY NAME OFFSET 24300000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 300000 ROWS ONLY" 
-ServerInstance "localhost\MSSQLSERVER2019" -U admin -P xxx -Database "222dbs" | Select-Object NAME,FULL_NAME,DOB,GENDER,ADDRESS | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100 | Out-File -Encoding ASCII C:\gen\\file_81.json
```

Appreciated your help!

Comment: what makes you think the issue is `Out-File` ? Are you sure your query returns the expected results ?

Comment: `out-File` is writing as expected for ~90 iteration, after that writing zero bytes.  I am sure my query is returning the expected result.

Comment: what happens if you change `Out-File -Encoding ascii` for `Set-Content -Encoding ascii` ?

Comment: Is `Set-Content` action similar `Out-File`? I used `Out-File` for write the result in .json file

Comment: Yes, the exact same.

Comment: The both `Set-Content`, `Out-File` are working fine when I ran the script manually in PS. It seems the issue occurring from`C#` PowerShell library `System.Management.Automation`.

Comment: I think you should share the full contents of your code to get the proper context on the issue. `Out-File` is most likely __not the issue__ here.

Comment: Most likely the issue is in `ConvertTo-Json`, I don't think it processes line by line and needs to receive all input before processing it (90gb of input, making the powershell instance to crash). Though this is based on assumptions, it would be easier to troubleshoot the issue if you try the code using 100% powershell instead of a pwsh instance from c#.

Comment: Select Query is hitting the famous 30 seconds timeout of the SMO object. I used the parameter `-Querytimeout 0` to fix zero byte issue.

Comment: You should post this a self-answer then so others with a similar issue in the future can see it

Comment: Sure:-) I will post as self-answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a self answer to my question so others with a similar issue in the feature can see it.

**I referred in Error Log**

Invoke-Sqlcmd : Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

**Solution**

The Select Query is hitting the famous 30 seconds timeout of the SMO object. I added parameter `-Querytimeout X` where X is time in seconds. 0 make infinite timeout we can use an integer value between 1 and 65535.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "Select NAME,FULL_NAME,DOB,GENDER,ADDRESS from [222db] ORDER BY NAME OFFSET 24300000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 300000 ROWS ONLY" 
-ServerInstance "localhost\MSSQLSERVER2019" -Querytimeout 0 -U admin -P xxx -Database "222dbs" | Select-Object NAME,FULL_NAME,DOB,GENDER,ADDRESS | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100 | Out-File -Encoding ASCII C:\gen\\file_81.json
```

Comment: Nice! I suggest to add line breaks and indentation after each `|` to make the code easier to read.